# A word for a book or list of people that you need to contact

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> I have to remember to contact Sarah sometime this week about the party, so I add her to my *person-listy-thing.*

I think there may be a (somewhat archaic?) concise term for this along the lines of 'datebook'. Thoughts?

**EDIT**: To clarify, this is a to-do list but with contacts' names; not simply a list of contacts.

Comment: What's wrong with *to-do list*? Or *calendar* (a list of things to do on certain dates)? For a while we called the electronic version *personal digital assistant* or *pda*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply say *contact list* or *call list*, as in *I have a dozen donors on my contact list for the weekend* or *We have 600 alumni on our call list for the campaign*. I am not familiar with any other term that refers specifically to a list of names to be contacted in the short term as part of a task list, though you could refer to calling the person as a task:

> I have to remember to contact Sarah sometime this week about the party. I'll add calling her to my to-do list.

In fact, I don't see what is wrong with *to-do* list, if it is understood that the person named is to be called.

> We've been calling everyone in the membership directory. Abramson through Lynd are done. I still have Mabel through Zukow on my to-do list, though.

The other suggestions either refer to a comprehensive list of contacts (e.g. address book, Rolodex) or documents or systems that do not necessarily involve contacting anyone (e.g. planner, agenda).

Comment: 'Call list' certainly sounds very close to what I was looking for; thank you! I think 'to-do list' is on the right track, though it starts getting a little creepy-sounding to have people on your to-do list, methinks! °-°

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

PLANNER--a chart for recording future appointments, tasks, goals, etc (Collins English Dictionary)

or DIARY or ORGANIZER.

Answer (score 3):

You said you were possibly looking for a somewhat archaic term.

The closest thing I could find, while looking, was *adversaria*.

[Definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/adversaria?showCookiePolicy=true)

Or, maybe, *memorandum*?

[Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/memorandum)

After the edit, I would suggest *agenda*, *docket*, *program*, or *schedule*.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the outdated term you're looking for is "[Rolodex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolodex)". This was a rotating card file that had indexes to make it easy to go to the entry you were looking for - still a pain if you had a lot of "M"s or "S"s.

Comment: You should probably clarify what a rolodex is.

Comment: Woops! So I should. Short explanation and link added.

Comment: This is definitely very close to what I'm looking for, though a Rolodex is more of a contact-book and less of a list-of-people-to-contact. Though one could definitely reorganize one's Rolodex to have a 'to-do' section; was that a common practice...?

Comment: (Incidentally, I've (in jest) written 'keep me in your Rolodex!' to people via email, only to have to explain what a Rolodex is.)

Comment: No, the Rolodex (as I remember them) was contact organization only, so maybe not exactly applicable. I do remember my older co-workers at NASA using a pocket calendar to remind them who to call, but keeping the name and phone number (this was pre-email) in their Rolodex so they'd not lose track of it.

Answer (score 1):

> *I have to remember to contact Sarah sometime this week about the party, so I add her to my **agenda**.*

**agenda**: a list of things to be considered or done

Answer (score 0):

A small book where you register the names of your friends and other contacts with phone numbers etc is an address book.

Comment: Sorry rugermue, I think my question was a bit unclear! I meant more along the lines of a to-do list (as per the edit). My fault!

Comment: See Google Bilder: address book. You'll find all sorts of calenders  for appointments.